# How to use case statement and min() with group by?

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query when I that execute

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN spd.IS_MAIN_DEFECT='Y' 
           THEN spd.piece_Defect_num_id 
         ELSE min(spd.PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID)
       END AS defect
  FROM piece P,
       STY_PIECE_DEFECT spd,
       STY_DEFECT_CATALOGUE sdc,
       piece_history ph,
       piece_history_out pho,
       PLANT_CONFIG pc
  (...inner join and where clause)
  GROUP BY p.PIECE_ID,
           CASE
             WHEN spd.IS_MAIN_DEFECT='Y'
               THEN spd.piece_Defect_num_id
             ELSE min(spd.PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID)
           end
```

It seems error

> ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

I guess , there is error min() in group by.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You have a `group by` column with an aggregation function.  Not only is that not allowed, but it does not make sense.  Also learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: find the min(spd.PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID) with appropriate grouping separately, and join that with the main query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `analytical MIN()` function like the below `without group by`

```
     SELECT distinct CASE WHEN spd.IS_MAIN_DEFECT='Y' 
      THEN spd.piece_Defect_num_id 
       ELSE min(spd.PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID) over () END AS defect
      FROM piece P , STY_PIECE_DEFECT spd ,STY_DEFECT_CATALOGUE sdc ,piece_history ph 
      , piece_history_out pho, PLANT_CONFIG pc
      (...inner join and where clause)
```

Comment: Thanks , but I have to use group by because of there are too many rows.

Answer (score 0):

I understood you want to preserve the `PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID` in rows with `IS_MAIN_DEFECT = 'Y'` and get the `MIN` value for the *non-main* defect lines.

The simplest solution for the case there is only *one row per `PIECE_ID`* with `IS_MAIN_DEFECT = 'Y'` - you group on `PIECE_ID, IS_MAIN_DEFECT`and calculates `min(PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID)`

which is fine a `MIN` for one row group is equal to the original value

```
select PIECE_ID,IS_MAIN_DEFECT,
min(PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID) PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID
from tab
group by PIECE_ID, IS_MAIN_DEFECT
order by 1,2 desc;
```

In case you can have *more rows* (same PIECE_ID) with the main flag, simple select them ungrouped and add the grouped *non-main* part using `UNION ALL`

```
select PIECE_ID,IS_MAIN_DEFECT,PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID
from tab
where IS_MAIN_DEFECT = 'Y'
UNION ALL
select PIECE_ID,IS_MAIN_DEFECT,
min(PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID) PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID
from tab
where nvl(IS_MAIN_DEFECT,'N') != 'Y'
group by PIECE_ID, IS_MAIN_DEFECT
```

Comment: Actually , the query you wrote has a function that is so close to what I want,but the problem both piece seems for IS_MAIN_DEFECT='Y' AND NON-MAIN.But I want to see ,if main_active_flag = 'Y', then first use this defect num id, else use min(defect_num_id)

Comment: @Hakanözel as already stated - post sample data and the expected result not the *if snippets*.